# fade-out of a showed div and fade-in of a hidden div on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I have 2 div: "secA" is the one that is showed at first, "secB" is hidden. Both div have a button that onclick show the other div and hide itself.
I want to make a fade-like transition from A to B and viceversa. A fade-in/fade-out transition it's ok, but if possible, a slide-left/slide-right animation would be better.

Here the HTML code:

```
<html>

<body>

  <div class=div1 id="secA">
    Section A<br/>
    <button class=button1 onclick="myFunction()">ToSectionB</button>
  </div>
  
  <div hidden class=div2 id="secB">
    Section B<br/>
    <button class=button2 onclick="myFunction()">ToSectionA</button>
  </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Here the CSS code:

```
.div1 {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;    
}
    
.div2 {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
    
.button1{
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
}
    
.button2{
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Here the JavaScript code:

```
function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("secA");
        var y = document.getElementById("secB");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            y.style.display = "none";
            x.style.display = "block";
        }
        else {
            y.style.display = "block";
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
}
```

Comment: You can make a class with the end position or end opacity. Then add CSS transition properties to the original class. Then, use JS to apply the new class. After the transition duration ends (offset with approx the same amount of ms), you can apply display: none (transition doesn’t work too well with display properties, hence the stepwise application of classes and styles). And then start doing the opposite with the other element to fade it in.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will work for you.

```js
function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("secA");
        var y = document.getElementById("secB");
        var d_time = '1s';
        if (x.style.opacity == '0') {
            y.style.opacity = '0';
            y.style.transition = d_time;
            x.style.opacity = '1';
            x.style.transition = d_time;
        }
        else{
            y.style.opacity = '1';
            y.style.transition = d_time;
            x.style.opacity = '0';
            x.style.transition = d_time;
        }
    }
```

```css
.div1 {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;    
}
    
.div2 {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
    
.button1{
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
}
    
.button2{
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class=div1 id="secA">
    Section A<br/>
    <button class=button1 onclick="myFunction()">ToSectionB</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class=div2 id="secB">
    Section B<br/>
    <button class=button2 onclick="myFunction()">ToSectionA</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: the code itself work, but not in my case, because I need the display properties. The fact is that i must implement all this code in Elementor editor, and i need to hide an entire section to not leave the space void. This code work if i put the "hidden" section over the other one using margin property. But doing this make the button still clickable even in opacity: 0, and create some difficulty for responsive management.